# How to have an efficient loop in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am calling some service that returns a response thru some callback function.
I used thread to call this service so that it is running in its own process.
The thread is called in my Main thread.

My question is how can I optimize my busy while loop in calling this service.
Sometimes the service fails and it is okay to just continue to retry looping in until a good response is received.

```
public class ProcessResponse extends Thread
    boolean isOK = false;

    public void responseReturned(Response response){
        //more code
        if(response.OK){
            //process result
            isOK = true; 
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            // call service
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if(isOK)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
My next line of thinking is just to use latch

```
public class ProcessResponse extends Thread
    boolean isOK = false;
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);


    public void responseReturned(Response response){
        //more code
        if(response.OK){
            //process result
            isOK = true;
        }
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(!isOK){
            // call service

            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //handle interruption
            }
            latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no sleep command but I am not sure if reinitializing the latch is a good approach.  The service sometimes takes time to return.
Note..I haven't tried this code yet.. I just type it in so I am not sure if this will work.

Comment: Why not just use an `ExecutorService` and get a `Future`?

Comment: Currently the main code does not use Concurrency Libraries so we are not able to use this.  I am working on extension so it is not allowed as of the moment. Do I hava another choice?

Comment: Are you using Java 9+?

Comment: It is still in Java 8.

Comment: I am thinking if exponential backoff of my Thread.sleep would help in this case? Do you think this is an OK solution?

Comment: Are Latch a much better alternative? See my update 2.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid ExecutorService and Callable. They are in java.util since 1.5, along with CountDownLatch. If CountDownLatch is available, so are the others. Also, they're all part of java.base if you're talking Java 9.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller I am thinking that it is a bit of an overkill to use executorservices for this.  I haven't use them to be honest and I find them adding a bit of complexity.  Although I am not that good in java thread programming.

Comment: @MarkEstrada Why dont you use CyclicBarrier, I think that will be a better approach and wont require reinitializing

Comment: @MarkEstrada Semaphore will also be a better approach here and  thread should only  be aquire it once released by responseReturned

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of options that are fortunately available in JAVA 5 which you can use:

**1) Cyclic Barrier:**
   Create a cyclic barrier of 2 and as the responseReturned will be called through main thread, you can simply put cyclic barrier await function to implement this. It has advantage that you can reuse the same barrier again and again without need to reinialize it.

**2) CountDown Latch** 
   Create a countdown latch of 1 and as soon as the responseReturned call the countdown function of latch, the await function in run will allow it to move ahead. It has a disadvantage that you have to reinitialize latch in case you want to reuse it.

**3) ExecutorService**
  You can also use ExecutorService and can call future object get method to wait till proper response is returned.

**4) Semaphore** You can also use aquire before calling the service and release it in responseReturned. In run you can again call aquire post call to wait till response is returned.

All of them will allow you to implement the functionality with almost similar efficiency.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Future interface may be used for these kind of interactions along with ExecutorService I guees. Once you submit a request ,you can set the timeout for the callback etc.

```
Future<String> futureTask = executorService.submit(callable);
String result = null;
try {
    result = futureTask.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```