# Alternative for synchronisation in multi threading in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am a beginner in Multi threading and have this one doubt:

Is there any other alternative for traditional Synchronisation(which uses synchronised keywords) in java,since it affects the performance of the application?

Comment: Synchronization requires stopping threads to prevent illegal accesses. If you need synchronization then you will lose performance.

Comment: I suggest you google a bit.... there are thousands of post explaining this. For instance this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50904456/1262248

Comment: Yes.  Question is what you want to avoid.

Comment: @vandench If you need synchronization you need synchronization, and 'lose performance' is meaningless, as you are comparing a correct implementation to an incorrect one. You can get the wrong answer in zero time if that's your only concern. It isn't relevant.

Comment: @EJP my point was that there is no way to avoid the performance issues. The `synchronized` is baked into the language, there a bits of it in the JVM klass, it is unavoidable.

Comment: The last thing you want to do while in the process of learning multi-threaded programming is worry about a 0.1% performance penalty.  All that counts at this point is ***correctness***.  Multi-threading is _really hard_.  If you have contention between threads then you have a performance impact due to the contention, not due to the mechanism of coordination.

Comment: @vandench *My* point is that there are no 'performance issues' to avoid, and that even talking about them is meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have indicated, it depends on what you're trying to avoid, as well as what you're trying to achieve with multithreading.

If you mean "is there a zero-overhead way to do multithreading with shared resources," the answer is almost certainly "no." If two cars going in different directions approach an intersection at the same time, one of them will have to wait for the other one - there's no way that the cars can occupy the same space at the same time. That's why we have stop signs and traffic lights. (Alternatively, there are things like traffic circles, but even those have some overhead - you really can't just go through them at full speed as if they weren't there).

There are lots of ways of doing asynchronous and parallel operations other than using that type of synchronization:

- Non-blocking I/O. The argument here is that, when you're interacting with a server or slow I/O device or something, most of the time is spent waiting for a response from the device or server, so you really don't need multiple threads to handle that - you just need to allow the original thread to do other work while it's waiting for a response. My usual analogy here is: suppose you go out to eat with a group of 10 people. When the waiter comes to take orders, the first person he asks to order isn't ready yet. The sensible thing to do, of course, is for the waiter to take other people's orders first, and then to come back to the first guy. There's no need to bring in separate waiters for each person's orders, bring in another waiter to wait for the first guy, or anything like that.
- Promise/futures based async
- Event-driven async
- Using immutable data structures to minimize the amount of shared resources.
- There are, of course, a lot of types of locking and synchronization mechanisms available other than just the synchronized keywords, such as counting semaphores, reader-writer locks, etc.

There are a lot of other types of concurrency as well, such as the [actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model).

When used properly, these can help minimize your overhead and possibly reduce the amount of explicit locking and synchronization required. They all have overhead, though.

**TL;DR** You have overhead no matter what you do - just select the design and primitives that result in the smallest overhead for your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock.